# Prove that $\|B\|_{\infty}<1$ with $B $ is defined by

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

Prove that $\|B\|_{\infty}<1$ with $B $ is defined by
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \frac{-a_{12}}{a_{11}} &\frac{-a_{13}}{a_{11}}  & \frac{-a_{14}}{a_{11}} \\
 \frac{-a_{21}}{a_{22}}&0  &  \frac{-a_{23}}{a_{22}}&  \frac{-a_{24}}{a_{22}}\\
\frac{-a_{31}}{a_{33}} & \frac{-a_{32}}{a_{33}} & 0 & \frac{-a_{34}}{a_{33}} \\
 \frac{-a_{41}}{a_{44}}& \frac{-a_{42}}{a_{44}}  & \frac{-a_{43}}{a_{44}}  & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Here $ \|B\|_{\infty}= \max_{1\le i \le 4}\left ( \sum_{j=1}^{n} |a_{ij}|\right )$

$\|B\|_{\infty}=\max\{\frac{a_{12}+a_{13}+a_{14}}{a_{11}},\frac{a_{21}+a_{23}+a_{24}}{a_{22}},\frac{a_{31}+a_{32}+a_{34}}{a_{33}},\frac{a_{41}+a_{42}+a_{43}}{a_{44}}\}$

But how to prove $\|B\|_{\infty}<1$ ?

Comment: Do you have any additional information about the $a_{ij}$? Otherwise I don't think the statement is true...

Comment: @noam.szyfer. no sir i don't have so im confusing

Comment: What does  $ \|B\|_{\infty}= \max_{1\le i \le 4}\left ( \sum_{j=1}^{n} |a_{ij}|\right )$ mean? Is that for your special $B$ or for an arbitrary $B = (a_{ij})$?

Comment: @PaulFrost. thats the definition of the inifinity norm on the matrix